# Replace function with multiple functions while respecting the inputs

Tags: function-construction, replacement

I want to replace a function with either one or two functions and also combine their arguments.

Say I have an original expression

```
expr = u[i + 1] r[i] r[i-1]
```

Then I want to to replace `u[i]` with `g[i+1] f[i-1]` in such a way that `expr` becomes

```
g[i+2] f[i] r[i] r[i-1]
```

If I were to feed in `f[i+1]`, then I would like to replace `u[i]` with `f[i+1]` so `expr` becomes `f[i+2] r[i] r[i-1]`.

I tried using pure functions by saying

```
q[h_] := expr /. {u -> Function[x, h[x]]};
```

but this didn't work, instead just putting `(h[x])[i+1] r[i] r[i-1]` when I enter a function `h[x]`.

The expression `expr` is a simple example, so I don't want to separate them into functions and arguments by hand.

Comment: I'm confused by "I want to replace `u[i]` with `g[i+1] f[i-1]` so `expr` becomes `g[i+2] u[i] r[i] r[i-1]`. I would read "I want to replace `u[i]` with `g[i+1] f[i-1]`" to  mean that the result should be `g[i+2] f[i] r[i] r[i-1]`. Is that right?

Comment: I can't seem to follow your replacement examples. Can you clarify? For instance, what do you mean when you say that you want to "feed in" a certain expression? Feed it in to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using pure functions, you can do the following.

```
expr = u[i + 1] r[i] r[i - 1];

replaceuWith[expr_, h_Function] := expr /. u[x_] :> h[x]
```

Alternatively,

```
replaceuWith[expr_, h_Function] := expr /. u -> h
```

Then,

```
replaceuWith[expr, g[# + 1] f[# - 1] &]
(* f[i] g[2 + i] r[-1 + i] r[i] *)

replaceuWith[expr, f[# + 1] &]
(* f[2 + i] r[-1 + i] r[i] *)
```

If you're uncomfortable with `Slot`s (i.e. `#`), then you can also call this as

```
replaceuWith[expr, Function[{i}, g[i + 1] f[i - 1]]]
(* f[i] g[2 + i] r[-1 + i] r[i] *)
```

---

A slightly more general version that also allows you to select what function name to replace:

```
repl[expr_, h_Function, x_Symbol] := expr /. x -> h
```

Then,

```
repl[expr, f[# - 1] &, u]
(* f[i] r[-1 + i] r[i] *)

repl[expr, f[# - 1] &, r]
(* f[-2 + i] f[-1 + i] u[1 + i] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want

```
expr = u[i + 1] r[i] r[i - 1]
expr /. u[n_] :> g[n + 1] f[n - 1]
(*  f[i] g[2 + i] r[-1 + i] r[i] *)
```